# How to set color for first row in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid on a wpf (mvvm) project.
the datagrid sort is showing the last item added to the collection as the first row.
i want to color the first row (in order to highlight new item added to the collection)
I've seen some similar questions about this manner but none of them are really related to what i am looking for.
i have tried to use a IValueConverter but it doesnt seems to be the right path for me as i need to get a unique identifier for the first row and change all the rest of the rows in order to classified it as a "First Row".

my object model for the items in the collection looks like this:

```
public class Messages
{
    public string Date {get; set;}
    public string Sender{get; set;}
    public string Content{get; set;}
}
```

*EDIT
Forgot to add the converter code...
of course this will color all rows to red, as i dont know how to affect the other rows when the collection changes.

```
class DateToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(value) >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1))
        {
            return "Red";
        }
        else
            return "Yellow";
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your DataGrid XAML and your ViewModel code, please?

Comment: it's a bit of a problem for me as its in an internal network and the viewmodel is huge. i can try posting the xaml (the datagrid context of course).
another update... when i debug it (slowly) its working fine, i mean only the first row is red and the others are yellow. but when i run it normaly its coloring all of them with red (i guess it has something to do with my converter and the time)

Comment: @Sag1v - How are you adding new item to the collection? Are you forcefully inserting it at 0th index?

Comment: Adding the item to a list that binds to the itemsource and sorting by date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **`RelativeSource`** with **`Mode`** set to **`PreviousData`** to identify whether dataGrid row is first one or not. For first row PreviousData will return null.

Apply DataTrigger on DataGridRow in ItemContainerStyle:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                  Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}}"
                  Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: wow what an elegant solution! seems to be working. what is <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>? I never used it..

Comment: `<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>` means style for item containers which will host content. For dataGrid its DataGridRow and for ListBox its ListBoxItem.

Comment: thanks!. i love this solution but it's a little "buggy", sometimes when i scroll the list down and up the green color moves to different rows (not consistent) very strange...

Comment: That's because of virtualization on dataGrid where it generate containers for only visible items and dispose the containers which are out of views. In your case if you are not dealing with large amount of data say 10000 rows or something, you can turn off virtualization and you won't see that issue. To turn off just set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` to `false` on dataGrid - `<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple solution if your data classes use some sort of an `Id` field. Let's say that newly added objects have an `Id` of `-1`, or `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` (to be updated/set upon a successful save). In this case, you could use a simple `DataTrigger` to change the `Background` of these items:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:Message}">
    <Border>
        <!--Define your Message UI here-->
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource YourNormalBrush}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="-1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource YourHighlightBrush}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: i thought of using an identifier but this way all of them would get an id of -1   wont they?

Comment: Only until they are saved... until then, their `Id` values are irrelevant other than to tell you that they're new and unsaved.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bool to your Model that will indicate the last element added :

```
    public class Messages
{
    public string Date {get; set;}
    public string Sender{get; set;}
    public string Content{get; set;}
    public string IsNew {get; set;}

}
```

and set the style of the DataGridRow based on that Property :

```
<Window.Resources>       
        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

In code above the blue will be the default style and the Red is for the new Rows

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">               
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Joseph what will make the existing items to be set as False when a new item is added to the collection? i will need to loop through the collection whenever i add an item and set all the existing items to isNew = false?

Comment: Each time a new item is added you need only to set the "IsNew" property of the previous "New" item

Comment: so why not use the date string as identifier for each message? its unique (contains seconds as well - dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss)

Comment: Yes you can, but in this case You will need a Converter in order to get the value used in the DataTrigger.